# New angular 8 project gives many console errors

Tags: angular8, .net-core-3.0

I've begun receiving a lot of errors in the console. This didnt impede development on a previous project for a while, but once it started causing premature exits I decided to see what a brand new project gave me. The same errors exist.

Errors:
- Websocket handshake failed: 'Connection' header is missing.
- Invalid host/origin header
- [WDS] Disconnected!
- Uncaught typeError: ___ is not a function

I'm completely at a loss on what to do for these errors, but it doesnt seem to be a code issue. maybe some libs or packages are not playing well?

any insight is helpful!

[image]

Comment: share more description about your project , package.json file and some other files.